# VBA Word - .Find "[space]" always find matches outside the selection range thus loops undefinitely

Tags: vba, ms-word

When converting a table from PDF to word, I ended up with a format similar to the following:

([space] is a space character)

Text  [space.spacing 10pts]   Text [space.spacing 30pts]      Text

Text  [space.spacing 14pts]   Text [space.spacing 31pts]      Text

Text  [space.spacing 12pts]   Text [space.spacing 33pts]      Text

Instead of a regular table with 3 columns and 3 rows containing each « Text » such as below

| Text | Text | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Text | Text | Text |
| Text | Text | Text |

In other words, instead of creating a column, the PDF conversion has created a regular paragraph, mimicking columns by adjusting [spaces].spacing according to the length of the text within the column.

So my inital thought was that it should be possible to recreate a table by identifing the spacing of each space for each paragraph of the converted table, eventually replacing them with identifiable symbols so I can convert the text into a table later on.

My idea was somewhat the following :

```
 ' For each paragraph of the selected text (which is the converted table)
    ' Find all [space] within the paragraph range
        ' If a [space] is found, check its spacing
            ' 1st case : [space].spacing is <= 1 pts (so a normal space)
                ' Do nothing
            ' 2nd case : [space].spacing is >= 10 pts (so previous Text is supposed to be within a small column) 
                ' insert ££ (symbol for small column)
            ' 3rd case [space].spacing is >= 30 pts (so previous Text is supposed to be within a small column) 
                ' insert §§ (symbol for large column)
 ' Once all [space] are found within the current paragraph, do the same with the next paragraph, until the last paragraph of the selected text
```

My current code is the following :

```
Private Sub Test()
Dim RngSearch As Range
Dim RngCurrent As Range
Dim Paragraph As Paragraph

For Each Paragraph In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    Set RngCurrent = Paragraph.Range
    RngCurrent.Select 'For testing purposes
    With RngCurrent.Find
        .Text = " "
        Do While RngCurrent.Find.Execute
            RngCurrent.Select 'For testing purposes
            Select Case RngCurrent.Font.Spacing
                Case Is >= 30
                    RngCurrent.Font.Spacing = 1
                    RngCurrent.InsertAfter ("§§")
                Case Is >= 10
                    RngCurrent.Font.Spacing = 1
                    RngCurrent.InsertAfter ("¤")
                Case Else
                    ' Do Nothing
            End Select
        Loop
    End With
Next Paragraph
End Sub
```

So it kinda word with one issue : it loops infinitely. Each time the text is finished, it goes back again indefinitely.

I managed to track the issue to the following code :

```
    With RngCurrent.Find
        .Text = " "
        Do While RngCurrent.Find.Execute
            RngCurrent.Select
            ' Use Case function
        Loop
    End With
```

Without it, the looping through paragraphs works normally (it ends at the last paragraph)

```
    For Each Paragraph In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        Set RngCurrent = Paragraph.Range
        RngCurrent.Select
        ' Code here
    Next Paragraph
```

But once `.find.text (" ")` is injected, it actually doesn't look within each Paragraphs.Range anymore as I supposed `Do While RngCurrent.Find.Execute` should have established.

I feel like the solution is something very stupid, but I've been searching for the reason why or alternatives for 2 days now. Everytime, it stops acting as per my understading when I'm using `.find(" ")`.

I already tried using `.wrap = wdFindStop`, but it stops at the first match within the paragraph, and goes to the next paragraph prematurely.

```
    With RngCurrent.Find
        .Text = " "
        .wrap = wdFindStop
        Do While RngCurrent.Find.Execute
            RngCurrent.Select
            ' Use Case function
        Loop
    End With
```

Strangely `.wrap = wdFindAsk` doesn't ask me anything... maybe that means something.

I believe it's because there are always spaces within each paragraph ? So it can loops indefinitely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found not exactly a solution but a workaround for anyone who may need a similar solution. Instead of using a .find =" ", I decided to go the "hard" path and check for every word in a paragraph (which in MS Word, seems to end with a [space] character). Then, I check for the last character of a word (which is often a space) if its spacing is superior to a value. It the case, do something.

```
For Each RngWord In Paragraph.Range.Words
    Set RngChar = RngWord.Characters.Last
    Select Case RngChar.Font.Spacing
        Case Is > 300
            RngChar.Font.Spacing = 1
            RngChar.InsertAfter ("£")
        Case Is > 100
            RngChar.Font.Spacing = 1
            RngChar.InsertAfter ("#")
        Case Is > 15
            RngChar.Font.Spacing = 1
            RngChar.InsertAfter ("¤")
        Case Else
            ' Do Nothing
    End Select
Next RngWord
```

It does the job, and isn't that slow, but I guess there are better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You're *way* over-complicating things:

```
Sub MakeTable()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Single
With Selection
  i = .Characters.First.Font.Size
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Text = " "
    .Replacement.Text = "^t"
    .Replacement.Font.Size = i
    .Font.Size = 10
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Font.Size = 30
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
  .ConvertToTable Separator:=vbTab
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I should have stated that unfortunately, due to PDF to Word conversion, the Font.Spacing is not always equal to 10 or 30. Sometimes it is equal to 11 or 13 but is still supposed to be within the first column, and same thing with the second column (font.spacing can be = to 30 or 32, or 35). That is why I though it was necessary to check for every space to see if its spacing is > 10 or > 30
So at least to my knowledge, I can't write something like [object].Find.Font.Spacing > 10 with VBA

Comment: It's a bit rich to change the question after the question as originally asked has been answered...

Comment: I am really grateful for the time you took. And I acknowledge that the inital contextual information might have been lacking some information to some extent, but I can't exactly say that the original question relating to how " .Find [space]" behave had really been answered. There was a reason why I wrote the former code that way although I wasn't clear enough about that reason. But again, it doesn't change the fact that I am grateful for the time you took and apologize for my rookie mistake.